# WooCommerce the first product image is repeated

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, repeat

This Website ([digitalzakka.com](https://digitalzakka.com/product/android-wireless-bluetooth-game-controller-gamepad/)) has been migrated, but the first product image is repeated.

[image]

There are no duplicates in the product gallery.

[image]

I also set a product image:

[image]

The product image and product gallery may be duplicated.

> I have `10,000` products, is there any way to solve this problem in batches?

Comment: The product image is automatically in the gallery.

Comment: Add product page URL

Comment: @mujunly hi, https://digitalzakka.com/product/android-wireless-bluetooth-game-controller-gamepad/

Comment: It has to do with the theme, probably if there is a product image, is being added to the gallery. We need the single product or part of the code to help further with that

Comment: Agree with @kaize: it might be helpful (or even provide the entire explanation!) if we could see the relevant theme template file or files (could also be a redundant function).

Comment: Not the optimal solution but you can use javascript in order to delete the first image element before the flex slider is loaded

Comment: You can use this hook to remove first gallery id from the list - woocommerce_product_get_gallery_image_ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in batches then a simple solution is to remove featured images from woocommerce products. Try the following code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'remove_featured_image', 10, 2);
function remove_featured_image($html, $attachment_id ) {
    global $post, $product;

    $featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

    if ( $attachment_id == $featured_image )
        $html = '';

    return $html;
}
```

I ran into the same issue. I solved it through the above code.

Comment: add this code to your currently active themes functions.php file and check

Comment: This will solve the problem for a certain type of installation (and may be just fine for this one), but it wouldn't be advisable in cases where the problem affected some or most, but not all products - in other words where you wanted to keep the featured image as an option for any products. To me, it's fixing bad data with PHP, at a cost to functionality. I won't say I've never done anything like this, but fixing the database isn't really very difficult (see earlier comment below).

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have added images in two places. First in the product featured image and second one in the product gallery images.

If you add some product in the product featured image you do not need to add that image in the product gallery image. So just remove that image from gallery and check it out.

Comment: Same problem happening in all product page?

Comment: Assuming @KrupalPanchal is correct, the next part is simple: You can try exporting products (ID and Images) as CSV, then use the spreadsheet to eliminate the first image url (and comma) in the Images Column, then importing the modified spreadsheet/CSV., or you can achieve the same effect programmatically. Even if you don't know how to manipulate the spreadsheet, you can still use a download to verify the issue. If there are exceptions, you should also see them there. Do you know how to achieve this result or do you need a full-fledged answer?